# MutableSet don't prevent duplicated content when using sealed class

Tags: kotlin

If I use `MutableSet` with `sealed class`, the `MutableSet` accept all duplicated content.

Sample:

```
sealed class LoginSavedCommand {
    class Login(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginSavedCommand()
    class SaveData(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginSavedCommand()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val mSet: MutableSet<LoginSavedCommand> = hashSetOf()

    mSet.add(LoginSavedCommand.Login("oba", "pass"))
    mSet.add(LoginSavedCommand.Login("faiii", "blabla"))

    if (mSet.add(LoginSavedCommand.Login("oba", "pass"))) {
        println("don't")
    } else {
        println("do")
    }
}
```

I passed the same values to `LoginSavedCommand.Login`, but the `MutableSet` keep accepting add the same value (on the sample `println` print "don't", and I need to print "do", because I need to prevent duplicated content using this `selaed class`)

Comment: i dont know what this sealed class is for in that context . .but what about using a data class (which automatically creates hashCode and equals Method) .. which i guess is missing in your case ;-)

Comment: @IEE1394 I need this sealed class, because I will use this on coroutine actors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `MutableSet` checks whether it contains an element by using the elements' [`equals` checks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) and, depending on the implementation, [`hashCode`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html). A `HashSet`, for instance, uses `hashCode` to store and quickly lookup the elements in a hash table.

The two subclasses of the `sealed class` in your example don't override the `equals` function and therefore provide the default equality check implementation, which is identity equality (i.e. an object is only equal to itself, and different objects are never equal even if their properties are equal).

To achieve uniqueness of `LoginSavedCommand` items within a `MutableSet`, you need to ensure the subclasses provide proper equality check implementation.

---

A simple way to do that is to [make both subclasses `data class`es](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), so that the compiler generates the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations based on the properties:

```
sealed class LoginSavedCommand {
    data class Login(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginSavedCommand()
    data class SaveData(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginSavedCommand()
}
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

---

Alternatively, override the `equals` and `hashCode` functions manually in the subclasses.

**Important:** when overriding these functions, ensure that the implementations follow the contracts of the functions described in the API reference for [`equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html) and [`hashCode`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html).

For example:

```
sealed class LoginSavedCommand {
    class Login(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginSavedCommand() {
        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            if (this === other) return true
            if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

            other as Login

            if (email != other.email) return false
            if (password != other.password) return false

            return true
        }

        override fun hashCode(): Int {
            var result = email.hashCode()
            result = 31 * result + password.hashCode()
            return result
        }
    }


    class SaveData(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginSavedCommand() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

<sup>These implementations where generated by IntelliJ IDEA, using the `Generate...` → `equals() and hashCode()` action within the class body.</sup>

Comment: Great and well organized answer!!! I tested and it worked. I think only keep data classes inside the sealed class is suficient, I only need this class types to pass values to coroutine actor.